# Getting an empty JSON array whenever I try to parse a URL response

Tags: java, json

I am working on a proof of concept to see if I can parse the response of X URL. I get an array of JSON objects Whenever I hit this URL on the browser, but I get an empty JSON array whenever I try to parse the same URL using the below Java code. I wonder if that is a normal behavior? Is there any explanation for it ? Am I using the right approach to get the data ?

```
{
 "campaigns": [
 ]
};
```

```java
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class HTTPGetTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://XXXX");
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            String jSONString= EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("jSONString : "+ jSONString);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }


}
```

Comment: Check the web service's API documentation.

Comment: Something tells me your HttpGet is not running properly, in other terms your URL is incorrect.

Comment: Mind providing the API you are trying to use? Might get more help.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, It has some sensitive data :(  but I wonder if that helps? We use it to inject some data using the JS tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://X"></script>`